# MSSQL query search with keyword list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got one table that contains all information about products. I need to list all articles with a matching keywords (in this case the brand name) in a specific column. Is it possible to initiate some kind of a 'list' with all brand names that I can use for this operation? chaning OR for all brands seems kinda bad.

In the second step I only need to see all articles that does not contain a specific word order before they keywords from the first step.

```
 DECLARE @brand NVARCHAR = 
    'bmw, toyota, mercedes'
SELECT [Artikelnum]
FROM [dbo].[LAGER]
  WHERE [XWebtexke] like '%' + @brand +'%' AND [XWebtexke] NOT LIKE '%suited for%' 
  GO
```

Thats what I got so far, but it does not work in the way I need it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Can you give us the table definition, or is it free of design ?

Comment: Actually some sample data would help, the query seems fine. Also, sample of what would you expect.

Comment: What kind of sample data do you need ?

Comment: Got another error, check my comment under your script

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @brand NVARCHAR = 
    'bmw, toyota, mercedes'


select * from (
SELECT [Artikelnum]
FROM [dbo].[LAGER]
  WHERE  [XWebtexke] NOT LIKE '%suited for%' )t4
WHERE [XWebtexke] like '%' + @brand +'%' 
  GO
```

Comment: Thanks but I get and errormessage: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'XWebtexke'.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @brand NVARCHAR = 
    'bmw, toyota, mercedes'


select * from (
SELECT [Artikelnum]
FROM [dbo].[LAGER]
  WHERE  [XWebtexke] NOT LIKE '%suited for%' )t4
WHERE t4.[XWebtexke] like '%' + @brand +'%' 
  GO
```

Comment: still returns an error message regarding and invalid column name for the last [XWebtexke] :/

Comment: Please cross check your column name (XWebtexke) weather its correct or not and its working for me on one my sample table on SQL server 2012.

Comment: the reason for this error is that you didn't pick XWebtexke in your subselect and you are asking for the value outside the subselect

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Oh yes , you need to include it in your Sub select like this :

Comment: select * from (
SELECT [Artikelnum],[XWebtexke]
FROM [dbo].[LAGER]
  WHERE  [XWebtexke] NOT LIKE '%suited for%' )t4
WHERE t4.[XWebtexke] like '%' + @brand +'%' 
  GO

Answer (score 0):

Realized you need all the keywords to match. Here is the solution for that.

You need to split the brand variable, try this:

```
DECLARE @brand NVARCHAR(200) = 'bmw, toyota, mercedes'

;WITH CTE as
(
     SELECT '%'+ t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')+'%' val
     FROM (
         SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
               REPLACE(@brand, ', ', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
     ) a
     CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
)
SELECT [Artikelnum]
FROM [dbo].[LAGER]
WHERE 
not exists(SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE [XWebtexke] not like val)
and [XWebtexke] NOT LIKE '%suited for%'
```

I am assuming there is always a space after the comma, you can adjust the code with ease if that is not always the case.

In sqlserver 2016 you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) instead of the split used in my answer